# Why subfigure are not centered

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I'm using beamer with subfigure. I would center it but doesn't work. Why? A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
            \begin{figure}\centering
                \parbox{1.3in}{
                    A
                }
                \qquad
                \begin{minipage}{1.3in}
                    B           
                \end{minipage}
            \end{figure}
        \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Weird solution: Move the centering commands into the parbox and minipage.

Comment: As percusse says: `\parbox` doesn't carry on the `\centering` command and resets to justified text.

Comment: You should be place a `%` after the `{` behind `\parbox`, otherwise you the line break will be taken as a space which will effect the effective alignment.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in next code, your figure is already centered, but what parbox and minipage contain is not centered. As percusse and egreg told you, move `\centering` inside both environments and you will have everithing centered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}

\lipsum[2]

        \begin{figure}
                \fbox{\parbox{1.3in}{%
                    A
                }}
                \qquad\fbox{%
                \begin{minipage}{1.3in}
                    B           
                \end{minipage}}
            \end{figure}

        \begin{figure}
                \fbox{\parbox{1.3in}{\centering
                    A
                }}
                \qquad\fbox{%
                \begin{minipage}{1.3in}\centering
                    B           
                \end{minipage}}
            \end{figure}

        \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]